# How to make a function return different strings when called at different times? C++

Tags: c++

In a class `Fox`, I need to build a function and return a string. And let's say `Fox* fox = new Fox();` The requirement is :

```
    std::string thing1 = fox->say();
    std::string thing2 = fox->say();
```

and `thing1 !=thing2`

So how can I achieve this?

I tried codes below but it has some error: `error: ‘foxWords’ does not name a type`

```
class Fox : public Canid{
    public:
        Fox(){
            int a = 0;
            std::vector<string> foxWords;
            foxWords.push_back("words1");
            foxWords.push_back("words2");

        };  // constructor is needed 


        string say(){
            a+=1;
            return foxWords.at(a%2);
        }   
        string name(){
            return "fox";
        }
};
```

Thanks to bwtrent I think you are right. I revised my code above and it returns error 
`‘foxWords’ was not declared in this scope` Is it because the `string say()` function was derived from a virtual function? The `say` function in Fox's parent function has to be made virtual.

Comment: you should first read [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/).

Comment: @Sionnach733 [the fox say.](http://www.jagd.bz/stimmen/mp3/fuchs.mp3)

Comment: does that even compile? I mean you cannot declare in the body of class like that. be specific what are you trying to ask.
see this first http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_classes_objects.htm

Comment: Yes I made a mistake. I revised code above but new error occurs.

Answer (score 4):

You are headed in the right direction, however, you should push elements to your vector in your constructor. Create your constructor, push those same elements, and you should be good to go.

You cannot push items like you are currently, It must be done inside of a function(probably the constructor).

Comment: yes you are right! I revised the code above, but also new error occurs saying ‘foxWords’ was not declared in this scope.

Comment: Why should he be using a vector to begin with?

Comment: `foxWords` is a local variable of the constructor. Declare `foxWords`, and `a` outside the constructor.

Comment: Thanks both bwtrent and @James Kanze gave me helpful advice!

Answer (score 1):

If the only goal is to return different strings, you don't need
a vector.  Something like:

```
class Fox
{
    int myState;
public:
    Fox() : myState( 0 ) {}
    std::string say()
    {
        ++ myState;
        std::ostringstream s;
        s << myState;
        return s.str();
    }
}
```

will ensure unique strings for a good number of calls.  Or you
can use `rand()`?

```
std::string Fox::say()
{
    int size = rand() % 10 + 1;
    std::string results;
    while ( results.size() < size ) {
        results += "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"[rand() % 26];
    }
    return results;
}
```

There are an infinite number of variants which could be used.

Comment: Yes I think I can use rand(). Do I need to include any header to use rand() ?

Comment: Oh I think it's done! The only thing is to change your while to if.

Comment: instead of changing to an if, you should decrement size in the while loop.

Comment: @rapdum Good idea:-).  Or better: `while ( results.size() < size )`.  (I've edited the answer to reflect your correction.)